# Google maps returning two different routes

Tags: google-maps, google-directions-api

I am surprised when I am finding the directions between two locations on google maps(maps.google.co.in) one using LAT, LNG, and the other one using the google suggested name. The routes returned are different.

Origin Address - 161 Keltner Ave, Spartanburg, SC 29302, USA.
Destination latitude and longitude - 35.554627, -82.853629

Link for address to address - https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/161+Keltner+Ave,+Spartanburg,+SC+29302,+USA/769+Champion+Drive,+Canton,+NC,+USA/@35.2324107,-82.6430623,10z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x88579ff345067667:0x5c96ddb575753f29!2m2!1d-81.8723738!2d34.9216748!1m5!1m1!1s0x88598319df45a533:0xe6a9cc5fe0824b95!2m2!1d-82.853377!2d35.5548676!3e0

Link for address to lat-lng - https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/161+Keltner+Ave,+Spartanburg,+SC+29302,+USA/35.554627,+-82.853629/@35.2321726,-82.404746,9z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m12!4m11!1m5!1m1!1s0x88579ff345067667:0x5c96ddb575753f29!2m2!1d-81.8723738!2d34.9216748!1m3!2m2!1d-82.853629!2d35.554627!3e0

Why is there so much difference? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I can't make out much of a difference in the two routes. This is the address to address route as I get it from your link:
[image: address to address nav]

This is the route I get from your address to lat/long link:
[image: address to lat/long]

The only significant difference is the end because the lat/long isn't 100% at the address and it appears you need to take a bit of a detour in the latter case:
[image: address – lat/long difference]

The measured difference is about 223 m:
[image: measured difference]

Comment: If Google Maps is suggesting to take a detour for one location it should do the same for the other one(as both of the locations are around 20 meters apart in the last screenshot - circle with a pin and circle without a pin).

Comment: I understand what you are trying to convey. So, I tried to run a new request from origin to destination as 769 Champion Drive(circle without the pin) using lat-lng i.e. 35.55492226784553, -82.85335739808949.

Comment: It is now showing the same(long U-turn route). [link](https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/161+Keltner+Ave,+Spartanburg,+SC+29302,+USA/35.55492226784553,+-82.85335739808949/@35.2318498,-82.6849359,10z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m12!4m11!1m5!1m1!1s0x88579ff345067667:0x5c96ddb575753f29!2m2!1d-81.8723738!2d34.9216748!1m3!2m2!1d-82.8533574!2d35.5549223!3e0)

Comment: Great, so does this answer your question?

Comment: Sadly, No. It looks like the issue is with Google Maps. For some reason, the lat-lng and address are not considered as the same.